# Ajax WordPress post popup with SimpleModal and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I tried to implement this mode here http://wordpressthemescollection.com/ajax-wordpress-post-popup-with-simplemodal-and-jquery-488.html but nothing seems to work.

This is what I do.

### 1 / Include in header

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>`
```

The links are goods cause I checked them both.

### 2 / Include in header this script

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.postpopup').live('click', function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('<?php bloginfo('url')?>/ajax/?id='+id).modal({
           opacity:90,
           position: ["0%"],
           overlayClose:true
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

### 3 / Make a custom template with this code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ajax
*/
?>
<?php
    $post = get_post($_GET['id']);
?>
<?php if ($post) : ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="whatever">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And after that made a page named Ajax and assign the template Ajax.

### 4 / Implement a link

```
<a href="javascript:;" rel="257" class="postpopup">this link</a>
```

If i click on the link nothing happens. 
What did I do wrong cause I did not have a clue about it?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you receive some error messages in your console?

Comment: no, when i click on the "This Link" nothing happens.

Comment: @Robo374 check in firebug(firefox) or web developers tool(chrome) on page load and on click event.

Comment: Please show use the HTML code generated after PHP generated it.

Comment: Where did you get the `.live('click',function(){})` syntax? I think it should be `.click(function(){})`.

Comment: Hi. I change to .click(function() and now when i click on the link the text is shown under the footer not in a popup as i want.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is ajax and so you need to do any subsequent things in a callback like this:

```
var $ajax-div = jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body');
var url = '<?php bloginfo('url')?>/ajax/?id=' + id;
$ajax-div.load(url), function() {
    // the callback
    jQuery('#ajax-popup').modal({
        opacity: 90,
        position: ["0%"],
        overlayClose:true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create an new post or page content on wordpress admin, select the "Ajax" template for your page

Comment: if you go in your admin panel and create a new page, you should be able to select this template as the page template. So I have created a page in WordPress called Ajax Handler with the template “Ajax Handler” assigned to it.